# Accessing External Website in Taskpane Office-addin

Tags: office-js

We trying to access below url in Taskpane Excel Office-addin but still it is opening as new window. I configured in Manifest file as Appdomain. But still not working. Hence kindly confirm anything need to check.

https://login.windows.net
 https://login.microsoftonline.com

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Identity Platform won't let it's login open in an iframe. I suspect that that is what you are running into. I recommend that you try the [Office Dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins). Also, see how it is used for auth at [Authenticate and authorize with the Dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/auth-with-office-dialog-api).